# Component Search - Component Used on Published Pages

Tags: 2013-sp1

What would be best and easy way to search the component list from a folder and its sub folder for all components used on published pages to particular target or any target without any custom code?

I am ok to perform multiple steps and also little bit manual effort

It is for SDL 2013 SP1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The code will be quite heavy from a performance perspective.  You'd look to:

1. Get the Components
2. For each Component, Where Used, filter for Pages (heavy)
3. For each Page, see if it is published to a target (medium)
4. Add to a list for processing later...

To Get the Components you could decide to do it either with the SearchAPI or the normal recursive GetListItems.

If you're performing this over hundreds or thousands of items, you might consider first creating the list of Components in an external datasource, such as SQLite, CSV file, XML file, etc.  Then, when processing the Components, mark each completed one as processed, and that way if the script stops for any reason, you can start back with the next item.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is no out of the box feature for this in SDL Tridion. At max you can utilizes the Virtual Folders/Advanced Search to found all components in a folder and subfolders which are published. To get a list of Components published to a particular target and/or to get a list of components associated on all published page, I guess you need to take help of core service and write a custom code.